# Rails 3.2.2 actions are being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My app is based on **`Rails 3.2.2.`** Faced some strange problem: all actions in development/production are called twice. Any suggestions?

```
Started GET "/faqs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-07 17:08:06 +0200
Processing by FaqsController#index as HTML
  Faq Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `faqs`.* FROM `faqs` WHERE `faqs`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY position asc
  Rendered faqs/index.html.haml within layouts/application (3.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation_bar.html.haml (5.3ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_register.html.erb (5.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 137ms (Views: 43.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/faqs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-07 17:08:06 +0200
Processing by FaqsController#index as */*
  Faq Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `faqs`.* FROM `faqs` WHERE `faqs`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY position asc
  Rendered faqs/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation_bar.html.haml (3.9ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_register.html.erb (12.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 30.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

---

**Updated #1**

Simple controller:

```
class FaqsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @faqs = Faq.all
    respond_with(@faqs)
  end
end
```

View is quite simple too:

```
%h2 Faqs
- @faqs.each_with_index do |faq, index|
  .span9  
    %h3
      = "%d." % (index + 1)
      = faq.title
    %p= faq.body
```

Comment: Looks like it might be jquery-rails. Pull up an inspector in your browser and see if you're doing some ajax-ey things.

Comment: The requests are for different mime types: `FaqsController#index as HTML` and `FaqsController#index as */*`. How in the world?!

Comment: @DeanBrundage There is no request made by AJAX.
c

Comment: @Zabba This is app is made from scratch, so there is nono changes in mime-types. Controller responds only with HTML.

Comment: How about posting the controller & view code for `/faqs`

Comment: It is very simple code, to test this issue.

Comment: @Maestro Were you able to resolve this? I am facing same issue in my app.

Comment: @Maestro I am also having the same issue. Any updates? It doesn't seem to be a client-side issue of it calling twice - Chrome's network request panel only shows one request. I am using PJAX so I am looking into that being the possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to Chrome. You can test in Safari/Firefox/IE etc

The reason I believe it causes two loads is because Chrome "forks" the request and essentially makes two requests. It renders the first one that returns in its window.

IIRC I researched this many years ago and this was a feature implemented to render pages faster.

Answer (score 0):

This issue probably does not have anything to do with Rails 3.2.2.

This exact behavior would be seen if you had javascript on your pages that was making an ajax request when the page was loaded. I would walk through all of your script assets and look for one that is meant to call back to your app after the page is loaded. You'll probably find the culprit there.